# 'vary' in APIM caching policies

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-caching

I am learning Apim policies.
In caching policies there is many elements of <vary-by....
In description of microsoft docs, it is mentionned that it caches by for example developer, query parameter...
What does it mean exactly?
Does this have a relation to refreshing values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies#GetFromCache

```
<cache-lookup vary-by-developer="true | false" vary-by-developer-groups="true | false" caching-type="prefer-external | external | internal" downstream-caching-type="none | private | public" must-revalidate="true | false" allow-private-response-caching="@(expression to evaluate)">
  <vary-by-header>Accept</vary-by-header>
  <!-- should be present in most cases -->
  <vary-by-header>Accept-Charset</vary-by-header>
  <!-- should be present in most cases -->
  <vary-by-header>Authorization</vary-by-header>
  <!-- should be present when allow-private-response-caching is "true"-->
  <vary-by-header>header name</vary-by-header>
  <!-- optional, can repeated several times -->
  <vary-by-query-parameter>parameter name</vary-by-query-parameter>
  <!-- optional, can repeated several times -->
</cache-lookup>
```

By default the cache lookup would only use the URL path as a reference (the cache key) to find the  cached item.

If you however wanted also to vary the cache lookup depending on a certain header or query parameter - with that extending the cache key - you would use `<vary-by-header>` or `<vary-by-query-parameter>` - so that for the same URL path responses are cached based on additional header and/or query parameters.

`vary-by-developer` or `vary-by-developer-groups` would extend the cache key with user or the group of the user assigned to the subscription key used - so that for the same URL path responses are cached based on who is calling the API operation.

Comment: Hi Kai. The url you mentioned is the course on which I was based.
so I am guessing that using VARY is to decrease response time and optimize search?

Comment: Hi @AbdessalemMANAI - caching in general of course should have a positive impact on response time. Using VARY just gives you more granularity of how a responses are cached - not only on URL path but also the other elements mentioned above.

Comment: Now I understand better. Thank you  Kai

Comment: What would happen if I put <vary-by-header>Authorization</vary-by-header> in the policy and I receive a JWT token in the Authorization header? Does not work caching?

Comment: @SamuelDavidGómezRamos hard to say. I would guess as a token in Authorization header could change very often that the caching has almost no effect. A cached value should be relatively stable and "un-complex" to see effects.