# APIM Cache base on query parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, caching, azure-api-management

I am working on Azure APIM. I have a endpoint as below. which take QueryParam as input. I would like to cache for 2 mins(If QueryParam is same).

In order to cache for 2 mins. I have to use outbound => Cache-store duration. **BUT did not find any example HOW TO CHECK THE Query parameter**

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <cache-store duration="seconds" />
        <base />
    </outbound>
</policies>

[HTTPGET]
Public GetProduct(QueryParam param) 
{
}

Class QueryParam {
 String productCode {get;set;}
 DateTime PurchasedDate {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['vary' in APIM caching policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127217/vary-in-apim-caching-policies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies#example):

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" downstream-caching-type="none" must-revalidate="true" caching-type="internal" >
            <vary-by-query-parameter>version</vary-by-query-parameter>
        </cache-lookup>
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <cache-store duration="seconds" />
        <base />
    </outbound>
</policies>
```

> When using vary-by-query-parameter, you might want to declare the parameters in the rewrite-uri template or set the attribute copy-unmatched-params to false. By deactivating this flag, parameters that aren't declared are sent to the back end.

[Policy statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies#policy-statement)

```xml
<cache-lookup vary-by-developer="true | false" vary-by-developer-groups="true | false" caching-type="prefer-external | external | internal" downstream-caching-type="none | private | public" must-revalidate="true | false" allow-private-response-caching="@(expression to evaluate)">
  <vary-by-query-parameter>parameter name</vary-by-query-parameter>
  <!-- optional, can repeated several times -->
</cache-lookup>
```

Comment: Thank you for response. How can I make sure that it use cache when parameters not change. if parameters change such as product code or product Date. Sorry I am new to APIM. Please advice

Comment: You find such information in the trace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector